# javascript:compare array objects and replace the value when match found

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare two array objects based on RoundNo and replace the confNo value in the List array , when match found in the confList Array mentioned below:

```js
const List = [{
    "Round": "1",
    "RoundNo": "R1-1",
    "noOfResubmit": "3",
    "confNo": "yyyy"
  },
  {
    "Round": "1",
    "RoundNo": "R1-1",
    "noOfResubmit": "3",
    "confNo": "yyyy"
  },
  {
    "Round": "1",
    "RoundNo": "R1",
    "noOfResubmit": "2",
    "confNo": "yyyy"
  },
  {
    "Round": "1",
    "RoundNo": "R1",
    "noOfResubmit": "2",
    "confNo": "yyyy"
  }
]

let confList = [{
    "Round": "1",
    "RoundNo": "R1-1",
    "noOfResubmit": "3",
    "confNo": "ABNCKJ"
  },
  {
    "Round": "1",
    "RoundNo": "R1",
    "noOfResubmit": "3",
    "confNo": "BJWVFRHE"
  }
]

List.map(function(x) {
  let result = confNoList.filter(a1 => a1.RoundNo == x.RoundNo);
  console.log("result" + JSON.stringify(result));
  x.confNo = result.confNo;
  return x
})

console.log("List :" + JSON.stringify(List));
```

Not sure why confNo is not printed in the output.
Output from the code above:

```
List : [
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1-1",
        "noOfResubmit": "3"
    },
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1-1",
        "noOfResubmit": "3"
    },
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1",
        "noOfResubmit": "2"
    },
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1",
        "noOfResubmit": "2"
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1-1",
        "noOfResubmit": "3",
        "confNo": "ABNCKJ"
    },
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1-1",
        "noOfResubmit": "3",
        "confNo": "ABNCKJ"
    },
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1",
        "noOfResubmit": "2",
        "confNo": "BJWVFRHE"
    },
    {
        "Round": "1",
        "RoundNo": "R1",
        "noOfResubmit": "2",
        "confNo": "BJWVFRHE"
    }
]
```

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `List.map()` to anything.

Comment: Is `confNoList` supposed to be `confList`?

Comment: sorry, yes it is confList

Comment: `filter()` returns an array of all the matching object, not a single object, so it has no `confNo` property. I think you want `confList.find()`.

Comment: filter returns array so either take [0]th. better use find. or you could convert confList to a lookup map and access

Comment: If you did `console.log(List)` you would have seen all the `confNo: undefined` in the result. But `JSON.stringify()` doesn't show properties with undefined values.

Comment: looks like confList.find() is working

Comment: @cmgchess, Thank you so much,[0]th makes sense and can you please help me with the details converting confList to a lookup map and access?